# Web api and IDS 4 Authorization: 401 on concurrent requests

Tags: identityserver4, identity, webapi

I'm working with Web Api and Identity Server 4 Auth. Whenever I call my API with a single request, I get a 200 response. However, when I do are 2 or more concurrent requests, I get 200 for one request and 401 for all others.

On the other hand, if I remove the authorization and I don't set the bearer token, I'm able to make several concurrent requests.

this is my debugging code:

```
async void Main()
{


    List<string> tokens = new List<string> {
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", //Removed tokens, but I'm actually using freshly created tokens with the appropriate scopes.
            };


    Console.WriteLine("=========TaskList==========");

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var t in tokens)
        tasks.Add(call(t));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); //Responds with one 200 and many 401


    Console.WriteLine("=========Await==========");
    
    foreach (var t in tokens)
        await call(t);      //Responds with 200s



    async Task call(string tok)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true
        };

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tok); //Removing this will let me do several concurrent calls. Adding it won't let me do concurrent requests even if authorization is removed from the server.
        var url = "https://localhost:44315/api/admin/user/GetUser"; 
        
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, "myUser");
        Console.WriteLine(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);

    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
 [ApiController]
 [Authorize(Policy = "AdminApi")]
 [Route("api/admin/user")]
 public class AdminUserController : ControllerBase
 {

        [HttpPost("GetUser")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(UserCreateResponseView), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromBody] string username)
        {
            var user = new MockUser(username);
            return Ok(user);
        }

}
```

I think this has to do with the bearer token handling and Identity Server 4 configuration but I don't know what to check next. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

EDIT: I was able to find the stack trace:

```
[16:34:33 ERR] JWT token validation error: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include[TEntity,TProperty](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 navigationPropertyPath)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore.FindClientByIdAsync(String clientId) in C:\local\identity\server4\EntityFramework\src\IdentityServer4.EntityFramework\Stores\ClientStore.cs:line 47
   at IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStoreExtensions.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(IClientStore store, String clientId) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Extensions\IClientStoreExtensions.cs:line 23
   at IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator.ValidateJwtAsync(String jwt, String audience, IEnumerable`1 validationKeys, Boolean validateLifetime) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Validation\TokenValidator.cs:line 301
```

Answer (score 0):

in identity server config in startup is same
is mine please check and send yours

```
        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });
           
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```